# getJson returns nothing

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I have a weird problem with getJson.

For example when I try to get a json with Nominatim like this :

```
var adresse = $('#ad').val();
$.getJSON( "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q="+adresse+"&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1", function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

It works.
But if I try to get from a file like this :

```
$.getJSON( "http://localhost/folder/address.json", function(data){

     console.log(data);
 });
```

My Json file is well loaded but there is nothing in data.

Could you help me to find what is wrong please ?

Comment: Check the json structure, and what is the response code for this request?

Answer (score 1):

You missed last `)` from `$.getJSON` on **server code** looks fine in **local code**

```
var adresse = 1;
$.getJSON( "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q="+adresse+"&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1", function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
 });
//^---- this is which you missed
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/3cnTH/)

Comment: You shouldn't need to add a callback unless you are sending JSONP rather than JSON.

Comment: The first code works fine but my problem is with the second code.

Comment: I think it's because my file is corrupted. It lacks some quotes.
Sorry for that !

Answer (score 1):

Check for errors :

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/...', function(data){ ... })
    .done(function(){ console.log('success', arguments); })
    .fail(function(){ console.log('failure', arguments); });
```

Your file may be served correctly, does it contain valid json data ?